# How to access a specific row in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I created a 3-column DataFrame with Pandas and I'm just trying to access the content of a specific row (there is a string inside).

```
tweets = pd.DataFrame()
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data)
tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data)
```

I thought that `tweets['text',0]` or `tweets.text[0]` would work but it's not the case

Comment: Sorry are you trying to do `tweets['text'] = tweets['text'].map(tweets_data)`?

Comment: Can also use tweets.ix[0] perhaps too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a specific sting you can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). It works as such:

**Getting data**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
id tweet
12  "this is the first tweet"
34  "this is the second tweet"
48  "this is the third tweet"
59  "finally the fourth tweet"
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')
```

**Using `str.contains`**

```
first = df['tweet'].str.contains('first')
this = df['tweet'].str.contains('this')
fin = df['tweet'].str.contains('finally')
```

That will result in:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: tweet, dtype: bool 0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: tweet, dtype: bool 0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: tweet, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, I just want to access what's inside the columns 'text with the row number x

Comment: Are you only interested in the index, or also the content of the column?

Comment: I'm only interested in the content of the column, but I think that `for x in xrange(0,len(tweets_data)):
 print tweets_data[x]['text']` would work just fine

Comment: FYI: for loops, in general, operate slower than using the API tools already built-in within pandas.

Comment: yeah, it must be, but the loop  returns me `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)` it seems that I can't acces `tweets_data[0]['text']` edt : I just add to used .encode

Comment: You need the proper encoding as mentioned by the error. It depends on how you load your data probably worth asking a question that's more related to that

Comment: I should also add it's worth googling that error as it's very common. This way you don't get flagged for duplicate question.